# How can I set up `translation file` for minikube cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I installed minikube in Mac OS and tried to launch a cluster by `minikube start`.
Below is the output of the command and in the first line it shows an error `Failed to load translation file for en: Asset translations/en.json not found`.

What should I do in order to fix the error message?

```
$ minikube  start
I1119 20:49:24.400748   39431 translate.go:89] Failed to load translation file for en: Asset translations/en.json not found
  minikube v1.15.0 on Darwin 10.15.6
  minikube 1.15.1 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.15.1
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.19.4 on Docker 19.03.13 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass, dashboard
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

when I run the version command it also gives me such error:

```
$ minikube version
I1119 20:55:15.654251   39700 translate.go:89] Failed to load translation file for en: Asset translations/en.json not found
minikube version: v1.15.0
commit: 3e098ff146b8502f597849dfda420a2fa4fa43f0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in minikube 1.15.0 ([kubernetes/minikube#9704](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9704)) and is fixed in minikube 1.15.1.  Follow the download link in the "start" command's output or upgrade it using your host system's package manager.